# Which company name I should write on resume?

Tags: resume

I am working for a small company owned by a big company .
The big company have full ownership of the small company I am working for.
My question is when I write my resume in working experience section ,can I use the big company name?
Or it’s better to simply write the small company name
Or like [big company- small company]

Comment: Who spins your checks? Big co or small co?

Answer (score 11):

There's no valid justification for using the big company name. It may own the small company, but you do not work for the big company, you work for the small company. Write that on your resume.

If I were hiring and I found that you "inflated" your resume by writing the big company name I would immediately remove you from consideration for the job. Writing big company is disingenuous and dishonest.

You might consider writing "Small Company, a subsidiary of Big Company" or something to that effect so long as it's legally factual.

Comment: At most, "Blivit Industries (now owned by General Conglomerate)". That makes your actual context clear, while suggesting that since GC bought the company they probably think there is something worthwhile about it.

Answer (score 1):

The safest and most universal option would be a formula like "Small Company (subsidiary of Big Company)".

Sometimes companies play carnival games with corporate structures (which are all under common management and influence) in order to fiddle their taxes or legal obligations, but the mere fact that one company is owned by another is not enough to justify putting the other owning company on your CV.

I mean, you can't say you worked for Goldman Sachs, just because they happen to own some tuppeny-hapenny factory that you actually work for.